# How do I disable a ribbon button on multiple select of records in account view in Dynamics 365?

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm-ribbon-workbench

I am working on dynamics 365. I need to disable a button, say assign, from the ribbon in case of multiple select in acccount view. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by straight forward `EnableRule` available named `SelectionCountRule`

[image]

[Read more](http://ankit.inkeysolutions.com/2015/07/selection-count-rule-display-ribbon.html?m=1)

Make sure to take a backup of Application ribbon/Entity before touching the customizations. Also you need to click the context menu “customize button” / “customize command” if you are customizing OOB button like Assign to retain the existing Rules/behavior & to add your custom rules/behavior.